# Кнопки на vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js

При нажатии на одну из кнопок пропадают все кнопки, а нужно чтобы пропадала только одна

```js
let app12 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    counter: 0,
    isHidden: true
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <h2>{{ counter }}</h2>
  <button type="button" @click="counter++" v-on:click="isHidden = !isHidden" v-if="isHidden">+1</button>
  <button type="button" @click="counter++" v-on:click="isHidden = !isHidden" v-if="isHidden">+1</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо назначить состояние для каждой кнопки:

```js
let app12 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    counter: 0,
    isHiddenButton1: true,
    isHiddenButton2: true
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <h2>{{ counter }}</h2>
  <button type="button" @click="counter++" v-on:click="isHiddenButton2 = !isHiddenButton2" v-if="isHiddenButton1">+1</button>
  <button type="button" @click="counter++" v-on:click="isHiddenButton1 = !isHiddenButton1" v-if="isHiddenButton2">+1</button>
</div>
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dealenx/5b4m1jxs/

Comment: Спасибо большое!